# Launching an intent for file : "Unable to find item"

Tags: android, android-intent, start-activity

I wish I could open any file type using mobile applications.

Here is the code :

```
    File mFile = new File( file.getLocalPath() + file.getFileName() );
    Log.i("path",  file.getLocalPath() + file.getFileName());

    if( mFile.exists() )
    {
        MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mFile.getName());
        String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        if (type == null)
            type = "*/*";

        Log.i("type", type);

        Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        Uri data = Uri.fromFile(mFile);
        Log.i("uri", data.toString());
        intent.setDataAndType( data, type );

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }
```

**Logs :**

- **Path** : `/data/data/com.package.name/files/sbx/523/filename.jpg`
- **Type** : `image/jpeg`
- **Uri** : `file:///data/data/com.package.name/files/sbx/523/filename.jpg`

All logs are displayed therefore the file exists.
However, during the opening of the gallery, I get an `"Unable to find item"`.

Where is the problem ? Are there other solutions ?

Comment: Are you using other app to open your image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to open file which is in android private area thats why during the opening of the gallery, you get an "Unable to find item". You have to put your file in local. If you want  to open a file of android private area you should be rooted.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I used a ContentProvider to open my files.